# Domain & Subdomain have same Domain Rating

Tags: seo, subdomain, seo-audit, seo-software

I'm doing SEO on a (relatively) new subdomain of an existing website.  I'm having an issue where I can't seem to find the subdomain's Domain Rating, Authority Score, or any similar metric without it just returning the value for that of the root domain.

Multiple tools, including but not limited to Semrush, ahrefs, and websiteseochecker.com, all report the domain and subdomain as having the same ratings.  This even applies to Historic Domain Rating (ratings over time), where such tools claim they've always had the same ratings, even before the subdomain existed.  The subdomain has existed for about 11-12 months now.

All articles and answers on the topic state unequivocally that root domain and subdomain ratings are entirely independent and have been of little help.

I've tried these tools on other domain/subdomain groups and the results were as expected - domains and subdomains having independent metrics.  Sadly, I'm not at liberty to share the exact URLs publicly.  Though I am more than happy to share the URLs privately, as it's a public website after all.

The client is very interested in learning about the Domain Rating statistics of the subdomain, and I'm not sure what to tell them in our meeting next week.  So, if anyone has an answer as to what might be causing this, or where I may be making an error, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thank you.

*Edit: I have already checked `robots.txt` and `.htaccess` with no luck

Comment: A domain includes all its subdomains.  My guess is that the tools just view the subdomain as part of the main domain and don't break it out separately.  Could you move this subdomain to a new domain to measure it separately?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I must stress how I've tested these tools on other domain/subdomain pairs, and they have been able to accurately differentiate them.  If I were to move the site to a new domain, it wouldn't carry its backlink profile with it, which would undoubtedly muddy the Domain Rating measurement.  Appreciate the input though.

Comment: Have you tried to open a support ticket with any of those companies?  I think you would be more likely to get an answer directly from them.  Maybe somebody here has some experience with this, but I'm not sure that any of our regular question answerers use these tools often.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I'd say it's worth a shot, but it's still very unusual that this applies specifically, **uniquely** to my website across various tools.  I'll give it a go.

Comment: Although I expect you are comparing your recently created subdomain with subdomains on other sites that have existed for a while.  Maybe these tools all fall back to the main domain when they don't have data?  Weird that they would ALL work that way though.